# Font shape `T1/~custom font~/m/n' undefined

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am using a custom font with pdfLaTex, using [this guide](http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php) and [this font](http://lotrazi.github.io/fonts/lotrazi_neue.otf). I replaced the "custom" strings in both the LaTeX command as well as the t1custom.fd file, but when rendering the document, the text appears in the original LaTeX font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{bookman}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\geometry{
tmargin=25mm, 
bmargin=24mm, 
lmargin=20mm, 
rmargin=20mm,
}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[md]{titlesec}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Not You}
\rhead{Lotrazi: The official guide}

\newcommand\lotrazi[1]{{\usefont{T1}{lotrazi_neue}{m}{n} #1 }}

\begin{document}
\title{Lotrazi\\\large The Official Guide}
\author{Not You}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section*{Preface}

\lotrazi{sdfghjkl}

\end{document}
```

The PDF is rendered, but the font is not used.

This is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.1)  21 AUG 2017 18:38
entering extended mode
**./lotrazi-official-guide.tex
(lotrazi-official-guide.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\bookman.sty"
Package: bookman 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\anyfontsize\anyfontsize.sty"
Package: anyfontsize 2007/11/22 anyfontsize.sty by pts
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\wrapfig\wrapfig.sty"
\wrapoverhang=\dimen111
\WF@size=\dimen112
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count90
\WF@box=\box26
\WF@everypar=\toks16
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty"
Package: titlesec 2016/03/21 v2.10.2 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box27
\beforetitleunit=\skip43
\aftertitleunit=\skip44
\ttl@plus=\dimen113
\ttl@minus=\dimen114
\ttl@toksa=\toks17
\titlewidth=\dimen115
\titlewidthlast=\dimen116
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen117
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks18
\inpenc@posthook=\toks19

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0100 (decimal 256)
   defining Unicode char U+0101 (decimal 257)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+0108 (decimal 264)
   defining Unicode char U+0109 (decimal 265)
   defining Unicode char U+010A (decimal 266)
   defining Unicode char U+010B (decimal 267)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0112 (decimal 274)
   defining Unicode char U+0113 (decimal 275)
   defining Unicode char U+0114 (decimal 276)
   defining Unicode char U+0115 (decimal 277)
   defining Unicode char U+0116 (decimal 278)
   defining Unicode char U+0117 (decimal 279)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011C (decimal 284)
   defining Unicode char U+011D (decimal 285)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0120 (decimal 288)
   defining Unicode char U+0121 (decimal 289)
   defining Unicode char U+0122 (decimal 290)
   defining Unicode char U+0123 (decimal 291)
   defining Unicode char U+0124 (decimal 292)
   defining Unicode char U+0125 (decimal 293)
   defining Unicode char U+0128 (decimal 296)
   defining Unicode char U+0129 (decimal 297)
   defining Unicode char U+012A (decimal 298)
   defining Unicode char U+012B (decimal 299)
   defining Unicode char U+012C (decimal 300)
   defining Unicode char U+012D (decimal 301)
   defining Unicode char U+012E (decimal 302)
   defining Unicode char U+012F (decimal 303)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0134 (decimal 308)
   defining Unicode char U+0135 (decimal 309)
   defining Unicode char U+0136 (decimal 310)
   defining Unicode char U+0137 (decimal 311)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013B (decimal 315)
   defining Unicode char U+013C (decimal 316)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0145 (decimal 325)
   defining Unicode char U+0146 (decimal 326)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+014C (decimal 332)
   defining Unicode char U+014D (decimal 333)
   defining Unicode char U+014E (decimal 334)
   defining Unicode char U+014F (decimal 335)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0156 (decimal 342)
   defining Unicode char U+0157 (decimal 343)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015C (decimal 348)
   defining Unicode char U+015D (decimal 349)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+0168 (decimal 360)
   defining Unicode char U+0169 (decimal 361)
   defining Unicode char U+016A (decimal 362)
   defining Unicode char U+016B (decimal 363)
   defining Unicode char U+016C (decimal 364)
   defining Unicode char U+016D (decimal 365)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0172 (decimal 370)
   defining Unicode char U+0173 (decimal 371)
   defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
   defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
   defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
   defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+01CD (decimal 461)
   defining Unicode char U+01CE (decimal 462)
   defining Unicode char U+01CF (decimal 463)
   defining Unicode char U+01D0 (decimal 464)
   defining Unicode char U+01D1 (decimal 465)
   defining Unicode char U+01D2 (decimal 466)
   defining Unicode char U+01D3 (decimal 467)
   defining Unicode char U+01D4 (decimal 468)
   defining Unicode char U+01E2 (decimal 482)
   defining Unicode char U+01E3 (decimal 483)
   defining Unicode char U+01E6 (decimal 486)
   defining Unicode char U+01E7 (decimal 487)
   defining Unicode char U+01E8 (decimal 488)
   defining Unicode char U+01E9 (decimal 489)
   defining Unicode char U+01EA (decimal 490)
   defining Unicode char U+01EB (decimal 491)
   defining Unicode char U+01F0 (decimal 496)
   defining Unicode char U+01F4 (decimal 500)
   defining Unicode char U+01F5 (decimal 501)
   defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
   defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
   defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
   defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
   defining Unicode char U+0232 (decimal 562)
   defining Unicode char U+0233 (decimal 563)
   defining Unicode char U+1E02 (decimal 7682)
   defining Unicode char U+1E03 (decimal 7683)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2010 (decimal 8208)
   defining Unicode char U+2011 (decimal 8209)
   defining Unicode char U+2012 (decimal 8210)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2015 (decimal 8213)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
   defining Unicode char U+1E20 (decimal 7712)
   defining Unicode char U+1E21 (decimal 7713)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
   defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
   defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
   defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
   defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
   defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
   defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
   defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty"
Package: fancyhdr 2016/09/06 3.8 Extensive control of page headers and footers
\fancy@headwidth=\skip45
\f@ncyO@elh=\skip46
\f@ncyO@erh=\skip47
\f@ncyO@olh=\skip48
\f@ncyO@orh=\skip49
\f@ncyO@elf=\skip50
\f@ncyO@erf=\skip51
\f@ncyO@olf=\skip52
\f@ncyO@orf=\skip53
)
(lotrazi-official-guide.aux)
\openout1 = `lotrazi-official-guide.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+pbk on input line 31.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\t1pbk.fd"
File: t1pbk.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pbk.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/pbk/m/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/pbk/l/n' tried instead on input line 31.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 483.69687pt, 56.9055pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(71.13188pt, 705.62836pt, 68.2866pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=483.69687pt
* \textheight=705.62836pt
* \oddsidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \evensidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \topmargin=-38.1381pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=50.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/pbk/m/n' in size <17.28> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/pbk/l/n' tried instead on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/pbk/m/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/pbk/l/n' tried instead on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 35.
[1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/pbk/m/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/pbk/l/n' tried instead on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lotrazi_neue on input l
ine 39.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1lotrazi_neue.fd. on input line 39.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lotrazi_neue/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 39.


Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.59999pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

[1] (lotrazi-official-guide.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1794 strings out of 493328
 21151 string characters out of 3145159
 80660 words of memory out of 3000000
 5332 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 13349 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,10n,43p,155b,196s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\ghass\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\
ecrm1095.pk>{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<C:/Progra
m Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/bookman/ubkl8a.pfb>
Output written on lotrazi-official-guide.pdf (2 pages, 17030 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 26 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I have gone through other questions, but the answer doesn't help me, as they are using fonts that come latex-ready, or are common system fonts, and not custom fonts.

I do not want to use the font for the entire document, and rather for specific text snippets.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added it

Comment: The `T1lotrazi_neue.fd` is not found. Did you rename the T1custom.fd?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes

Comment: Well as it is not found you either didn't give it the correct name or it is not in a place where latex can find it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's working now, please repost comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log-file the `T1lotrazi_neue.fd` is not found. Check that you correctly renamed the `T1custom.fd` and that it is in a place where LaTeX can find it.